# Help creating 3d object view with Accelerometer in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, mobile, cinemachine

Hi I would like to create a object view controlled by mobile accelerometer so it gives a AR impression like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A8olJzeAYg.
So this is what I tried so far. I created a cinemachine freelook camera and set my object to its look at target. Then using this script I move camera based of accelerometer data:

```
 private void Update()
{
    MoveCamera();
  
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(-dirX, 0, 0);
}

private void MoveCamera()
{
    dirX = Input.acceleration.x * lookSpeed;
    dirZ = Input.acceleration.z * lookSpeed;
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, rightBorderX, leftBorderX),
         Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, downBorderY, upBorderY),  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, bottomBorderZ, upBorderZ));

}
```

The problem is it gets further away from the cube when it moves left or right so I would need to move my camera on z axes closer to the object as it moves on one of its sides.

Comment: "I'm not sure if that would really work" - sounds like you should try it and find out. What specific step did you get stuck on when you tried to implement it [based on the available documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-attitude.html)?

Comment: Didn't try it out yet because I'm not sure if I should start there or are there some other methods that are mostly used for this.

Comment: Try first. If your method works, then it doesn't matter if other ways work too. If your method doesn't work then you can ask a more specific question about how to fix that problem.

Comment: I tried it and edited the question.